# How can I customise my page layout?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I have created a page in liferay 7 with an image diplaying at full width. Under the image I want a 3 column layout. How can I achieve this? Do I just add some WebContent with some custom css?

I have created a new template in here:

```
C:\Users\me\Documents\workspace\my-workspace\bundles\tomcat-8.0.32\webapps\ROOT\layouttpl\custom\1_column_3_columns.tpl
```

The tpl looks like this:

```
<div class="portlet-layout row">
    This is the full width row
</div>
<div class="columns-3" id="main-content" role="main">
    <div class="portlet-layout row">
        <div class="col-md-4 portlet-column portlet-column-first" id="column-1">
            $processor.processColumn("column-1", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-first")
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 portlet-column" id="column-2">
            $processor.processColumn("column-2", "portlet-column-content")
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 portlet-column portlet-column-last" id="column-3">
            $processor.processColumn("column-3", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-last")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am not sure how to deploy this because when I look at the settings for a random page I dont see this 'new' layout(the file is called 1_column_3_columns.tpl):
[image]

I am not sure whether I deployed this the right way. From the commandline I ran:

```
blade gw build
blade gw deploy
```

How can I deploy / create this new .tpl layout for my site?

Comment: Will code for bier

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add apps in the 3 columns below the picture, the best approach would be to create a layout.

Should be 5 min of work. Best copy the OOTB 3 column one and add one row over the 3 columns.

https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/layout-templates-intro

EDIT:

If you use blade tool for deploying have a look at https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/blade-cli.

If you run then deploy command you should see a message in the tomcat log indicating that the layout was deployed and is started. 
Alternatively just compile the code `./gradlew build` and then copy the war file form build to `LIFERAY_HOME/deploy/`

A not to the Template. If you want to place portlets in the top row, you need to put the placeholder code there with a unique indicator.

```
<div class="portlet-layout row">
    $processor.processColumn("column-0", "portlet-column-content")
</div>
```

And maybe just to clean thing up I would go with.

```
<div class="columns-1-3" id="main-content" role="main">
<div class="portlet-layout row">
    $processor.processColumn("column-0", "portlet-column-content")
</div>

<div class="portlet-layout row">
    <div class="col-md-4 portlet-column portlet-column-first" id="column-1">
        $processor.processColumn("column-1", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-first")
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 portlet-column" id="column-2">
        $processor.processColumn("column-2", "portlet-column-content")
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 portlet-column portlet-column-last" id="column-3">
        $processor.processColumn("column-3", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-last")
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, check your layout-template.xml file if you are pointing to the right files.

Comment: How do I create a layout?

Comment: Added the link to the answer

Comment: I tried this but the new layout does not appear in the configuration afterwards?

Comment: are you sure that the plugin deployed properly?  Can you see it active in gogo shell?

Comment: Mate I am a beginner , what gogo shell?

Comment: the OSGi console. you can access it via ```telnet localhost 11311``` . Also when you copy the layout template plugin into the deploy folder you should see a message in the log saying that it's deployed.

Comment: How do I copy the OOTB 3 column ?

Comment: do you have telnet installed? are you executing it on localhost? It should not fail.